# Populate jsGrid(1.4.1) with correct json call......getting empty table

Tags: javascript, datagrid, jsgrid

I've been trying different CRUD grids for jquery and I came across this one which is pretty good. I made a previous post using a different grid plugin but that did not met my needs so I'm trying this one. The table displays correctly but with empty rows.

I'm getting this response from the server which I validated with a JSON online validator

```
[{"id":"1","anio":"2016","mes":"1","quincena":"1"},{"id":"2","anio":"2016","mes":"1","quincena":"2"}]
```

this is the script made in symfony 1.4 to build the json:

```
 public function executeGetNewsletters(sfWebRequest $request){

    $conn = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection();

    $qry=$conn->execute("Select id,anio,mes,quincena from newsletters");

            $newsletters = $qry;

            $dataNews = array();

                foreach ($newsletters as $news)
                    {

                           $dataNews[] = array(
                                "id" => $news['id'],
                                "anio" => $news['anio'],
                                "mes" => $news['mes'],
                                "quincena" => $news['quincena'],
                            );

                    }


            echo json_encode($dataNews);

              return sfView::NONE;





  }
```

this is the js file that holds the grid:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   



    $("#newsletters").click(function(){$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/newsletter/getNewsletters"
        }).done(function(newsletters) {

        //  newsletters.unshift({ id: "0", name: "" });

            var news=newsletters;

            alert(news);

            $("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
                height: "90%",
                width: "100%",
                datatype: 'json',        
                sorting: true,
                paging: true,
                filtering:true,
                autosearch: true,
                editing:true,
                autoencode: true,
                gridview: true,
                mtype: 'POST',
                colNames:['ID','Año', 'Mes','Quincena','Option'],

                data: news,

                fields: [
                    { name: "id", type: "number", width: 150 },
                    { name: "anio", type: "number", width: 50 },
                    { name: "mes", type: "number", width: 200 },
                    { name: "quincena", type: "text", textField: "Quincena" },
                    { type: "control" }
                ]
            });


        });
    });
});
```

and this is the html that holds the grid:

```
   <?php use_javascript("jurisprudencia/newsletter.js")?>

     <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.4.1/jsgrid.min.css" />
     <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.4.1/jsgrid-theme.min.css" />

     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.4.1/jsgrid.min.js"></script>


    <body><div class="col-lg-7 col-lg-7-bc">
        <h3 style="font-size:20px"> JURISPRUDENCIA</h3>

        <p>

            </br>

        </p>


           <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 item ico "><a id="newsletters" target="_blank">Newsletters |</a></div>

           <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 item ico "><a  id="fallos" target="_blank">Navegar |</a></div>

           <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 item ico"><a id="cuadernos_mpd" target="_blank">Cuadernos del MPD</a></div>


            <div id="jsGrid"></div>


     <script>

    </script>




    </div>
```

I could not find the accepted format on the jsgrid documentation. Does anyone know which is the correct format?. Thanks

Comment: The format seems correct. Are you sure that data coming from server not as a string but parsed JSON?

Comment: One more thing: you used unsupported config parameters `datatype`, `autoencode`, `gridview`, `mtype`, and `colNames`. Find supported configuration [here](http://js-grid.com/docs/#configuration). Also you used grid with static `data`, it's better to define `controller: { loadData: function() { return $.ajax(...); } }` like described [here](http://js-grid.com/docs/#grid-controller). All this should not be the reason, but anyway better to fix.